# Forces on the wall and floor of a dirt filled box

Tags: forces

A box is filled with dirt. What are the forces on the wall and floor? Assume the box is $10\times 5\times 3 \space (L\times W\times H)$, the density of dirt is $2000 kg.m^{-3}$ and the angle of repose is $30$ degrees. The box is heaped. For the love of me, I can't figure it out. Ok, the box can be split into 5 different parts:

- part of the dirt with forces acting against the front wall of the box and the floor
- part of the dirt with forces acting against the left wall of the box and the floor
- part of the dirt with forces acting against the right wall of the box and the floor
- part of the dirt with forces acting against the back wall fo the box and the floor
- part of the dirt with forces acting against the floor

The part of dirt with forces acting against the floor only is easy: just find the part that doesn't have any horizontal forces (a triangular prism with the plane angle of angle of repose). But the other ones don't seem to have a logical force distribution.

Because for me it doesn't seem reasonable that with an angle of repose of $30$ degrees, the part of the dirt acting against the front wall is more than the part of the force acting against the floor.

Schematic of the box and forces.

[image: schematic]

Is it actually like that, or am I making a mistake in my logic?